# Fermion propagator decomposition

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices

I've seen the following decomposition for the fermion propagator for a fermion with momenta $p-k$, and where both $p-k$ and $p$ have a mass of $m$:

$$\frac{(\not p-\not k)+m}{(p-k)^2-m^2}\gamma_\mu=
\frac{2p_\mu-k_\mu}{k^2-2k\cdot p}- \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}[\not k, \gamma_\mu]}{k^2-2k\cdot p}$$
Can anyone explain why this decomposition is correct? The denominator is obviously correct, but I can't see how the elements of the numerator add up.

Any ideas?

**Addendum:**

The original formulation comes from [this](http://th-www.if.uj.edu.pl/~siodmok/PhD/papiers/YFS/YFS1961.pdf#page=57) 1961 paper (page 435), where it appears as:

[image]

As I understand it, the bold text refers to the slash notation, not the 3-vector component.

Comment: Is this decomposition completely general or:

1) It might be in some special representation e.g. Pauli-Dirac etc...

2) It might be in some limit, e.g. non-rel limit. 

3) It might be in some special frame?

Comment: @LoveLearning - I believe so. It is possible that's it's only valid couple with an external photon propagator $\epsilon_\mu^*(k)$, but I don't see how that changes anything.

Comment: Can you put up some references where to find that decomposition?

Comment: @LoveLearning - see the attached link, page 57:
http://th-www.if.uj.edu.pl/~siodmok/PhD/papiers/YFS/YFS1961.pdf

Comment: @JamalS - this edit is incorrect. In modern notation bolt text refers to the vector part, not the slash.

Comment: @nbubis: As the edit states, I copied from the PDF *verbatim*, using the original author's notation.

Comment: @JamalS - Thanks, but I was afraid that this would add confusion due to the rather old notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as you say, the denominator is OK. For the numerator we use 
$$\tag{1}\not a\gamma_{\mu} = 2a_{\mu}-\gamma_\mu\not a, (\text{follows from } \{{\mu,\nu \} = 2\eta_{\mu\nu}}). $$

Then the numerator can be written
$$Num = 2p_\mu-k_\mu-\zeta_\mu$$
where $$\tag{2}\zeta_\mu:=-k_\mu+\not k\gamma_\mu+\gamma_\mu\underbrace{(\not p-m)}_{=0 \text{ when hitting }u^{(s)}(p)}. $$

Now compare with 
$$\tag{3}\frac{1}{2}[\not k,\mu] = \frac{k^\nu}{2}(\nu\mu-\mu\nu) = \frac{k^\nu}{2}(\nu\mu-\mu\nu+\mu\nu-\mu\nu) = k_\mu-\gamma_\mu\not k=-k_\mu+\not k\gamma_{\mu}, $$
which is almost $\zeta_\mu.$ One can now rewrite $\zeta_\mu$ as equation $(3)$ by using the on-shell equations of motion,
$$\tag{4}0=(\not p-m)u^{(s)}(p), etc.,  $$
because remember that in the original paper we have the gamma structure sandwiched between  $\bar{u}$ and $u$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a nitpick: \not x is clearer than \not{x}, and $\gamma_\mu$ clearer than $\mu$ :)

Comment: OK thanks because I don't know whats the best "slashed" here on PSE. And yes I agree with your second remark, but sometimes the gammas get kind of redundant, especially in the intermediate steps of calculations :)